# Scrapy + Eclipse PyDev : how to setup the debugger?

Tags: eclipse, pydev, scrapy

I've successfully setup Eclipse with my Scrapy project.

I did it by setting a new Run/Debug configuration :

- Whose main module links to Scrapy /usr/local/bin/scrapy for me (I've found suggestion to use cmdline.py but that failed on my computer (OSX Lion & scrapy installed through easy_install)
- Defining the arguments to send "crawl ny" in my case as I would if I used the Scrapy command line
- Setting the correct working directory (${workspace_loc:My Project/src} in my case)

Eclipse can successfully launch my project, but I've no debbuger. I'm missing my breakpoints and variable inspection, does anyone know how to setup the debbugger with this environment ?

Answer (score 9):

- Keep the whole scrapy project folder under PyDev.
- You Need to set the main module to scrapy/cmdline.py
- Set arg to `crawl ny` in your case

[image]

Answer (score 1):

None of the suggestions above worked for me. Things would run, but no break points would fire.

I added a main.py file to my local project and hooked into the scrapy command line like so:

```
import scrapy.cmdline

def main():
    scrapy.cmdline.execute(argv=['scrapy', 'crawl', 'wiki'])

if  __name__ =='__main__':
    main()
```

This could easily be further refined to pass in the spider name to have different debug configs per spider.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're running it properly from inside Eclipse already, isn't it just a matter of running it in debug mode?

I.e.: if you followed the instructions from: http://pydev.org/manual_101_run.html (regarding the setting to "Always launch the previously launched application"), after running your module in regular mode, just press F11 to run it in debug mode.

Comment: The custom main module disable this feature I think. I know how to use Eclipse, it's the Debug mode which is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved this for my environment, with the Scrapy package in a virtual environment outside the project directory:

1) Create a simlink to your cmdline.py from inside the project, something like:

```
ln -s ../venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py cmdline.py
```

2) Refresh the project so you can see it, then set that as the main module in the debug configuration.

3) In the "Arguments" tab in the debug configuration, where it says "Working Directory", select Other and then enter, or navigate to using the buttons, the Scrapy directory in your project.